# Redirect to previous action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In old versions of MVC you used to be able to do this:

```
public ActionResult MyNextAction()
{
    return Redirect(Request.Referrer.ToString());
}
```

What is the equivalent in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Try this  - `string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();`

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!